# MDX Prior Quarter Day Range

Tags: sql, time, mdx, business-intelligence

I've been tasked with a rather odd Time intelligence function by my finance group that I'm trying to puzzle out.

I've been asked with creating a measure within our SSAS Cube to allow for seeing previous quarter to date based on how far we are in the current quarter.  But instead of seeing a standard idea of days elapsed currently versus days elapsed previously, they would like to see days remaining versus previous days remaining.

What I mean by that is, take 1/22/2015 for example.  We have 48 days remaining in our current quarter, which I have by means of a calculated measure.  I need to find the corresponding working day from the previous quarter where it is also at 48 days remaining.

At that point I could create a date range with some aggregate functions off of the first date in the previous quarter to the corresponding date found in the above and come up with what they are looking for.

The best idea I've had so far is to possibly do this in the database section itself, by creating a new column that is essentially the calculated number of days remaining but stored.  But at that point I'm not sure how to take a calculated measure in SSAS and filter a previous quarter date member to use that property as it were.

Comment: just re-read your question - you need equivalent quarter to date but measured from the end of the quarter - rather than the traditional method which is from the start of the time period?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an utility dimensions in your cube? We have one called TimeCalculations. In there we have things such as CurrentValue, MTDValue, PrevEquivMTD, Past7Days .... I think your new logic would fit in with such a dimension.

Here is an example of PrevEquivQTD against AdvWrks that I just had a play with. Guessing this doesn't really help your scenario but I had fun writing it:

```
WITH 
  SET [NonEmptyDates] AS 
    NonEmpty
    (
      [Date].[Calendar].[Date].MEMBERS
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    ) 
  SET [LastNonEmptyDate] AS 
    Tail([NonEmptyDates]) 
  SET [CurrQ] AS 
    Exists
    (
      [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Quarter]
     ,[LastNonEmptyDate].Item(0)
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[pos] AS 
    Rank
    (
      [LastNonEmptyDate].Item(0)
     ,Descendants
      (
        [CurrQ]
       ,[Date].[Calendar].[Date]
      )
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[PrevEquivalentQTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      Head
      (
        Descendants
        (
          [CurrQ].ITEM(0).PrevMember
         ,[Date].[Calendar].[Date]
        )
       ,[Measures].[pos]
      )
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[pos],[Measures].[PrevEquivalentQTD]} ON 0
 ,[LastNonEmptyDate] ON 1
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
      [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20050111]
    : 
      [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20080611] ON 0
  FROM [Adventure Works]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Date is **1/22/2015**. You want the ***Same Date in Previous Quarter*** which would be **8/22/2015**.

If this is what you want, you will have to use MDX function ParallelPeriod as shown in sample below. Please replace it with your own Dimensions and Cube.

```
Select
ParallelPeriod
( 
[Date].[Calendar Date].[Calendar Quarter],    -- Level Expression
1,                                            -- Index
[Date].[Calendar Date].[Date].&[20150122]     -- Member Expression
) On 0 
From [Adventure Works]
```

If you want the same date in the following quarter, then replace index 1 with -1.

Cheers